# Passing Custom Variable at End of URL in facebook.com/sharer not working

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-sharer

I'm trying to add a facebook share button to my page

Here's the code

```
<a  href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.test.com/default.aspx?S=Facebook&SID=3688"
```

Now when the share the link of facebook, I lose **&SID=3688**

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

URL Encode your href value, then you shouldn't "lose" anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should encode this `u=http://www.test.com/default.aspx?S=Facebook&SID=3688` because facebook gates value in a same way as your site by using query string.

Feel free to create your own implementation based on this. Make sure you URL encode the u and t parameters -- use the JavaScript function `encodeURIComponent()`. For example:

http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sadtrombone.com%2F&t=Sad%20